# Call a function after another function is complete in React

Tags: reactjs, callback

The first function `postOpenai` was called in `useEffect()` to get data  and `setState` `setWriting` successfully , then I try to call function `splitFunc` after.  I use callback in `setWriting()` like following:

```
     const [writing, setWriting] = useState(null);
     const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
     const [error, setError] = useState(null);

     const postOpenai = async function () {
          console.log(params);
          await Parse.Cloud.run("postOpenai", params)
               .then(resp => {
                    setWriting(resp[0].text, () => {
                         splitFunc()
                    });
                    setIsPending(false);
                    setError(null);
               })
               .catch(error => {
                    setError("Failed to generate", error);
                    setIsPending(false);
               });
     };

     let writingSets = [];

     const splitFunc = () => {
          console.log(typeof (writing))
          writingSets = writing.split("\n");
          console.log(writingSets);
     };

     useEffect(() => {
          console.log("1", writing);
          console.log(Boolean(writing == null));
          if (writing == null) {
               postOpenai();
          } else {
               alert("alert! can not repeatedly generate ")
          }
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 
     }, []);
```

I get an error: `state updates from the usestate() and usereducer() hooks don't support the second callback argument.`

[image]

So I try using `useEffect()` to run the second function `splitFunc()` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
          console.log("2" + writing);
          splitFunc()
     }, [writing]);
```

It failed again, gets errors showing `setWriting()` hasn't been succeed: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')`
[image]

How do I manage this , could any one help? Thank you!!

Comment: `setState` doesn't take second argument, it's not a class component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: It doesn't work using useEffect() as well... do I miss something?